# JPA Entity with relation to itself not populating Foreign key

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, join, entity

I have a table called "Accounts".
On this table, there will be parent and sub accounts tied to a parent.
My idea is to use a single entity, with One-To-Many and Many-To-One relationship.

Entity looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Accounts implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column(name = "ACCOUNT_ID", nullable = false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "account_id_generator")
@SequenceGenerator(name="account_id_generator", sequenceName = "ACCOUNT_ID_seq", allocationSize = 1)
Long accountId;

@Column(name = "ACCOUNT")
String accountType;

@Column(name = "FK_SUB_ACCOUNT")
Long fkSubAccount;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "subAccount")
List<Accounts> subAccounts = new ArrayList<>();

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "fk_sub_account", updateable = false, insertable = true, referenceColumn = "account_id")
Account subAccount;

...
Some other attributes here, they are being populated by jpa

}
```

How I populate:

```
var account = new Account();
account.setAccountType("Parent");

var subAccount = new Account();
List<Account> subAccounts = new ArrayList<>();
subAccount.setAccountType("Sub");
subAccount.setSubAccount(account);
subAccount.getSubAccounts.addAll(List.of(account));
account.setSubAccount(subAccount);
subAccounts.add(subAccount);

account.getSubAccounts().addAll(subAccounts);

repository.save(account);
```

I am able to see all attributes except for the fkSubAccount - which is null.
Anything I am doing wrong?

I had some tables with similar setup except they are on different entities, and they work fine.

Comment: The field `Long fkSubAccount` is mapped to the same column as the relation `Account subAccount` - `@Column(name = "FK_SUB_ACCOUNT")` and `@JoinColumn(name = "fk_sub_account", ...)` respectively. I bet Hibernate gets confused. In fact you do not need the `fkSubAccount`, just drop that field and see what happens.

Comment: I you want direct access to the "parent" account id, make sure you define the `fkSubAccount` as `insertable=false, updatable=false`.